# python binary search tree

Tags: python, search, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

For some reason, I can't seem to get the "find" method to work.  I think it has to do with a scoping issue... the root.val doesn't seem to update globally. I get an error message saying AtributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val' 
Here is my code at the moment:

```
class BinaryNode:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.val = v
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None
    def get(self):
        return self.val
    def set(self, v):
        self.val = v
    def getChildren(self):
        children = []
        if self.leftChild != None:
            children.append(self.leftChild)
        if self.rightChild != None:
            children.append(self.rightChild)
        return children

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    def setRoot(self, node):
        self.root = node
    def size(self):
        if self.root == None:
            return 0
    def subtreeSize(node):
        return 1 + sum(subtreeSize(c) for c in node.getChildren())
        return subtreeSize(self.root)

class BinarySearchTree(Tree):
    def insert(self, val):
        self.insertNode(self.root, val)

    def insertNode(self, node, val):
        if node is None:
            self.setRoot(BinaryNode(val))
        elif val <= node.val:
            node.leftChild = insertNode(BinaryNode(val), val)
        elif val > node.val:
            node.rightChild = insertNode(BinaryNode(val), val)
        else:
            node.val = val


    def find(self, val):
        self.findNode(self.root, val)

    def findNode(self, node, val):
        if node is None:
            return False
        elif val == node.val:
            return True
        elif val < node.val:
            self.findNode(val, node.leftChild)
        else:
            self.findNode(val, node.rightChild)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    btree = BinarySearchTree()
    vals = [5]
    for v in vals:
        btree.insert(v)
    tests = [8, 5]
    for t in tests:
        print "find(%i) = %s" % (t, ("True" if btree.find(t) else "False"))
```

Comment: Why would you delete the question and deny others the help that you received?

Comment: Please, do *not* remove the question. You posted this under the CC Wiki license (see bottom right of the page) and your question is meant to help *others* in the future too.

Comment: If you feel you posted this in error (don't want your professor to find out?) then you need to [request to be disassociated from the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki). Do not simply vandalize it and deny those that helped you the reputation and recognition.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with your `findNode()` method:

1. You *swapped* the `node` and `val` arguments when you call it recursively. This causes your code to try to look up `.val` on the integer value instead of the node.
2. You forgot to return the recursive call results.

Corrected methods:

```
def find(self, val):
    return self.findNode(self.root, val)

def findNode(self, node, val):
    if node is None:
        return False
    elif val == node.val:
        return True
    elif val < node.val:
        return self.findNode(node.leftChild, val)
    else:
        return self.findNode(node.rightChild, val)
```

Your next problem is your `insertNode` method; you try to call a global `insertNode()` function in it; that should probably be `self.insertNode()` instead. However, that method has *no* return value, so you end up setting `node.leftChild` or `node.rightChild` to `None`.

You want to just hand over the search for the insertion point to a recursive call, no need to use a return value:

```
def insert(self, val):
    if self.root is None:
        self.setRoot(BinaryNode(val))
    else:
        self.insertNode(self.root, val)

def insertNode(self, node, val):
    if val <= node.val:
        if node.leftChild:
            self.insertNode(node.leftChild, val)
        else:
            node.leftChild = BinaryNode(val)
    elif val > node.val:
        if node.rightChild:
            self.insertNode(node.rightChild, val)
        else:
            node.rightChild = BinaryNode(val)
```

With these changes, your simple test prints:

```
find(8) = False
find(5) = True
```

Comment: (+1) Well spotted on the swapped arguments. I've been puzzling over the exception, and this explains it.

Comment: @BobertHido: Not helpful enough, I take it? Anything else wrong? I tested the code a little more, it works for me as it stands now.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with `findNode()` is that you are missing `return` statements. The

```
    elif val < node.val:
        self.findNode(val, node.leftChild)
    else:
        self.findNode(val, node.rightChild)
```

should read

```
    elif val < node.val:
        return self.findNode(val, node.leftChild)
    else:
        return self.findNode(val, node.rightChild)
```

You have a similar problem in `insertNode()`.